# How to get access to new c++11 standard sized types?

Tags: c++, c++11

The types I am talking about are shown on page 3 here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13100941/C%2B%2B11.pdf

int8_t
uint8_t
int16_t
uint16_t
int32_t
uint32_t
int64_t
uint64_t

I am using Visual Studio 2012.  If it's different for GNU/Mingw include how to get them on those compilers too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include `<cstdint>`. It will work for any **C++11** or **C99** conformant compiler.

And for those compilers where `<cstdint>` is not available or is broken, there is [*Boost.Integer*](http://www.boost.org/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/cstdint.html).

Comment: @AshRj: For any **C++11** or **C99** conformant compiler

Comment: Note that providing these types is *entirely optional* for the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `#include <cstdint>` which is in MSVC since version 2010.